# Can Qorum Blockchain supports partail transaction encryption?

Tags: blockchain, quorum

My use case is that we need to protect sensitive data in the transaction in blockchain.  But we want to open other data in the same transaction to the public,  Can Quorum support the above mentioned transaction type?  If not, any other blockchain platform support it?

Please advise.  Thanks.

Wilson

Answer (score 1):

In quorum, a transaction is either public or private. I can't see how it could be both and I'm not aware of any blockchain that would support that.
For a use case where part of the data is public and part of it is private, I think folks would usually separate the data into two transactions.
You could also manage this via a (public) smart contract, which makes the decision around whether the data is public or private and creates the transaction accordingly.